# How power Arduino Mega 2560?

Tags: arduino, power-supply, power

I want to run Arduino Mega 2560 outdoor for long time.
I found this choices:

**1 - 12 V power jack:** It makes the board so hot so I skip it.

**2 - Vin:** It makes the board so hot so I skip it too.

**3- 5 V pin:** It worked. I heard it makes Arduino unstable because it bypasses the regulator inside it.

How can I solve this? Will 5 V pin work good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5V pin will work good yes. this powers the MCU directly and without issues.

Regarding the issue of the "Regulator bypass",this may be a problem because you put 5V in the output of the Regulator (instead of its input).

IF the circuit is designed correctly, the regulator should have a diode (D1), which directs the 5V that you put in its output, to its input like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fakUon.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Even if the diode is not there, It should not make the Arduino unstable.

Comment: It could be unstable if the voltage you give it is unstable.